# Building Google mtail image from official Dockerfile fails

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I am trying to build mtail image using the Dockerfile from https://github.com/google/mtail/blob/master/Dockerfile

Steps I followed,

1. Created a file named Dockerfile in my local directory. Copied contents from the above link to this file.
2. ran command to build image  `docker build -t mtail .`

But build is exiting with this below error message,

> make: *** No rule to make target 'depclean'.  Stop.
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c make depclean && make install_deps && PREFIX=/go make -B install' returned a non-zero code: 2

Tried removing `make depclean` from Dockerfile, then it fails with,

> make: *** No rule to make target 'install_deps'.  Stop.
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c make install_deps && PREFIX=/go make -B install' returned a non-zero code: 2

Could not find any help in documentation,
https://github.com/google/mtail/blob/master/docs/Building.md

Thanks,

Sandeep

Comment: and did you copy all required files? you need to clone the entire repo and start the build I think

Comment: Now I cloned the repo and then ran build command. This time it ran for a while but again exited with error,

`go: finding github.com/prometheus/client_model v0.0.0-20190115171406-56726106282f
go: error loading module requirements
make: *** [Makefile:117: mtail] Error 1
The command '/bin/sh -c make depclean && make install_deps && PREFIX=/go make -B install' returned a non-zero code: 2`

Comment: @LinPy thank you, cloning the repo and running the build worked on 2nd time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @LinPy
It was failing due to missing dependencies. Solution was to clone the entire repo of mtail, and then use Dockerfile from this to build image.